# Enable Wi-Fi disappeared?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

My wireless card has been working fine until I installed the latest update.  Now the `enable wireless` setting is completely gone from the applet in the top launcher.  Enable networking is still there.  This is my wireless card info:

After rebooting without hardwire:

```
ole@MKI:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

With hardwire:

```
    ole@MKI:~$ iwconfig
    veth8804537  no wireless extensions.

    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    lo        no wireless extensions.

    br-d6801a10bc52  no wireless extensions.

    vethfa5d674  no wireless extensions.

    veth236d2de  no wireless extensions.

    docker0   no wireless extensions.



    ole@MKI:~$ ifconfig
    br-d6801a10bc52 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:fa:7a:67:d4  
              inet addr:203.0.113.254  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::42:faff:fe7a:67d4/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:680 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:11368 (11.3 KB)  TX bytes:117173 (117.1 KB)

    docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:32:a6:65:07  
              inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::42:32ff:fea6:6507/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:1956 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:2351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:607490 (607.4 KB)  TX bytes:578053 (578.0 KB)

    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:1d:48:c2:a9:81  
              inet addr:192.168.1.9  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::a21d:48ff:fec2:a981/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:269630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:158993 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:294183781 (294.1 MB)  TX bytes:22427423 (22.4 MB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:9713 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:9713 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:836695 (836.6 KB)  TX bytes:836695 (836.6 KB)

    veth8804537 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 46:d4:42:f2:3d:5b  
              inet6 addr: fe80::44d4:42ff:fef2:3d5b/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:1956 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:2467 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:634874 (634.8 KB)  TX bytes:591237 (591.2 KB)

    veth236d2de Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:37:ae:f5:26:74  
              inet6 addr: fe80::fc37:aeff:fef5:2674/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:801 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:11256 (11.2 KB)  TX bytes:131095 (131.0 KB)

    vethfa5d674 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e2:05:30:83:0e:36  
              inet6 addr: fe80::e005:30ff:fe83:e36/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:815 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:12641 (12.6 KB)  TX bytes:142736 (142.7 KB)


    ole@MKI:~$ iwconfig
    veth8804537  no wireless extensions.

    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    lo        no wireless extensions.

    br-d6801a10bc52  no wireless extensions.

    vethfa5d674  no wireless extensions.

    veth236d2de  no wireless extensions.

    docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Please post the output from iwconfig and ifconfig -a

Comment: I deleted the lspci -nn output.  Please let me know if you needed.

Comment: I presume that lspci lists your wireless hardware, correct?  I see that all of your traffic is going over enet0.  Try disconnecting the ethernet cable, rebooting and then re-check iwconfig.  It's certainly possible that the upgrade bombed the card's drivers.  You didn't say what version of Ubuntu you are running.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 - Will try rebooting without the hardwire.

Comment: Someone else is having an identical wifi issue on 14.04.  In his case, he downgraded to resolve an unrelated issue.  I'm not a Ubuntu version guru but my understanding is that 16.04 LTS is the latest long term support version.  Might be worth looking at the 14.04 release notes to see if they just introduced a wireless bug into the latest update.

Comment: hmmm .... yeah seems like it completely nuked the network driver ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your test results it appears that the recent 14.04 update introduced problems with detecting wireless hardware.  And not just your model PCI wifi hw, apparently.

So your options (all rather painful) seem to be

1) Wait for a fix and use wired ethernet in the meantime.  There are several similar problem reports out there so a fix might not be long in coming.

2) Roll back to the previous version of 14.04

3) Upgrade to the current LTS release of 16.04